# three-dimensional sizes in FHIR

Tags: hl7-fhir

What would be the preferred means of describing the size of 3-dimensional object such as a tumor  in FHIR?

Extending one of the existing resources, such as Observation, with  3 fields for x, y, z extents seems reasonable, but not particularly general.

Ideally, one might extend complex data types to include a new type. However, I don't see any provisions for extending data types.

Is there a preferred approach to the creation of new models for concepts such as 3-dimensional measurements?

Comment: Some "keyword search" tips may be in the article [hl7standards.com: 5 Questions With Tim Dawson, Chief Architect at Vital Images](http://www.hl7standards.com/blog/2013/11/07/dicom-rs/). Found by using  `fhir 3d` as the initial keyword search. Welcome to Stack Overflow, and in case that none (out of the 48 people monitoring this tag) will provide some useful answer, feel free to post [self-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) for posterity

Answer (score 0):

FHIR has an extensibility model (http://www.hl7.org/fhir/extensibility.html) that not only covert extending the Resources but also the datatypes.

That said, I think you should model this as 4 Observations, one representing the main grouped measurement (with no value) and 3 Observations (for x,y,z) to which the main measurement refers using Observation.related (type=hasComponent).

This pattern is a bit verbose. If we would look at extensions, I don't think this is an extension on Observation, but rather an extension on Quantity. That would raise the question: which of the 3 dimensions goes into Observation.value?

Comment: The rationale for Observation is that all of the characteristics of Observation, such as when the measurement was made, who did it, how they did it, uncertainty of the measurement, etc. apply.  If the tumor is expected to be a long-standing trackable thing, the tumor itself can be represented using BodySite (though an initial Observation would establish the existence of that BodySite).

Comment: Ewout, thanks for pointing out that data types can be extended. I see how three or four observations could be used, but that seems to be a bit dissatisfying. Even extending Quantity would seem to be a bit ugly. 

lmckenzi, I see how the tumor could be represented as a an Observation/BodySite, but I still don't see how the dimensions could be included.

Ideally, there might be a "Volume" data type. That would seem to be the cleanest way to go.  Is there any possibility of extensions in the form of new DataTypes/Resources?

Comment: ""Even extending Quantity would seem to be a bit ugly"" - I agree. I will take it up with the team.